# Can a first level Cleric utilize the feat Versatile Channeling?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, class-feature, cleric, channel-energy

My level 1 lawful neutral cleric picked Negative Energy Channeling. His level 1 feat is Versatile Channeling, which allows characters to channel the opposite energy at two levels weaker.

Can he use Positive Channeling even though he is a level 1 Cleric that picked negative Channeling?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

He can channel positive energy as a “cleric of level −1,” which is to say, not at all since the ability to channel energy becomes available at cleric 1st. The feat offers no “minimum 1st” provision that you often see in these sorts of situations.

He nonetheless meets requirements for channeling positive energy, even though he can’t actually, because the feat explicitly says he does.

Finally, usual note that channel energy is a weak class feature, and a poor choice for feat investment.